# Find top N most frequent categories with top N most frequent sub-categories for each category

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a single query that will retrieve:

The top e.g. 3 most popular brands from a list of cars. For each of the top 3 brands I want to retrieve the top 5 most popular models.

I tried with both a ranking/partitioning strategy and a `distinct ON` strategy but I cannot seem to figure out how I can get the limits to works within two queries.

Here is some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e81d5/1

From the ranking query I would expect an output like this, given the sample data (order not important):

```
brand       car_mode    count
'Audi'      'A4'        3
'Audi'      'A1'        3
'Audi'      'Q7'        2
'Audi'      'Q5'        2
'Audi'      'A3'        2
'VW'        'Passat'    3
'VW'        'Beetle'    3
'VW'        'Caravelle' 2
'VW'        'Golf'      2
'VW'        'Fox'       2
'Volvo'     'V70'       3
'Volvo'     'V40'       3
'Volvo'     'S60'       2
'Volvo'     'XC70'      2
'Volvo'     'V50'       2
```

Comment: `LATERAL` join.

Comment: Thanks! That was the clue I needed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e81d5/9

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I could use `LATERAL` join as suggested in comments. Thanks.

```
SELECT brand, car_model, the_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT brand FROM cars GROUP BY brand ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 
  ) o1
INNER JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT car_model, count(*) as the_count
    FROM cars
    WHERE brand = o1.brand
    GROUP BY brand, car_model
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 5
  ) o2 ON true;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e81d5/9

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using cte and window function `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select brand,car_model,count(*) as cnt from cars group by brand,car_model
 ) , cte2 as
 (
     select * ,row_number() over(partition by brand order by cnt desc) rn from cte
 )
select brand,car_model,cnt from cte2 where rn<=5
```

[demo link](https://rextester.com/JASMQ80033)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select brand, car_model, cnt_car
from (select c.*, dense_rank() over (order by cnt_brand, brand) as seqnum_b
      from (select brand, car_model, count(*) as cnt_car,
                   row_number() over (partition by brand order by count(*) desc) as seqnum_bc,
                   sum(count(*)) over (partition by brand) as cnt_brand
            from cars c
            group by brand, car_model
           ) c
     ) c
 where seqnum_bc <= 5 and seqnum_b <= 3
 order by cnt_brand desc, brand, cnt desc;
```

If you know that each brand (or at least each top brand) has at least five cars, then you can simplify the query to:

```
select brand, car_model, cnt_car
from (select brand, car_model, count(*) as cnt_car,
              row_number() over (partition by brand order by count(*) desc) as seqnum_bc,
              sum(count(*)) over (partition by brand) as cnt_brand
      from cars c
      group by brand, car_model
     ) c
where seqnum_bc <= 5 
order by cnt_brand desc, brand, cnt desc
limit 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :-)